# How to pass index value in replace method

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I am trying to create a replace method for a class, but I am struggling in understanding how to pass the index of the replacement. Here is a toy example:

Here is the `ExampleClass`:

```
# class definiton
setClass('ExampleClass', representation(lists = 'list'))

# class constructor
ExampleClass <- function(lists){
  ec <- new('ExampleClass', lists = lists)
}
```

And here are my getter and setter methods:

```
setGeneric('seeLists', function(x) standardGeneric('seeLists'))
setMethod('seeLists', 'ExampleClass', function(x){
  return(x@lists)
})

setGeneric('seeLists<-', function(x, i, value) 
standardGeneric('seeLists<-'))

setMethod('seeLists<-', 'ExampleClass', function(x, i, value){
   x@lists[[i]] <- value
   return(x)
})
```

Now if I create an object of `ExampleClass` class I can access the items in the lists field.

```
testObj <- ExampleClass(list('a' = c(1:3), 'b' = c(4:6)))

seeLists(testObj)
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6

seeLists(testObj)[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

But if I wanted to replace one of them, how do I indicate the interpreter which parameter is `i`.

```
newitem <- c(7:9)
seeLists(testObj)[[2]] <- newitem

Error in x@lists[[i]] <- value : [[ ]] with missing subscript
```

I guess that the way that I defined the `seeLists<-` replace method is wrong, could someone enlighten me which is the correct way? Bonus: what if it was a 2-dimensional object, how would you define `j`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common confusion, when we call

```
foo(myObject)[[i]] <- value
```

this is interpreted as follows:

```
*tmp* <- {foo(myObject) <- value}
*tmp*[[i]] <- x
*tmp*
```

So you can modify your definition of `seeLists<-` to be

```
setMethod('seeLists<-', 'ExampleClass', function(x, i, value){
  return(ExampleClass(value))
})
```

and it will work as desired. It may look strange, but the `[[<-` is handled automatically in this case and you don't need to write that yourself, since the default behaviour of `[[<-` works in this case (if it didn't, you would need to write a separate method for `[[<-`.)

```
> testObj <- ExampleClass(list('a' = c(1:3), 'b' = c(4:6)))
> newitem <- c(7:9)
> seeLists(testObj)[[1]] <- newitem
> testObj
An object of class "ExampleClass"
Slot "lists":
$a
[1] 7 8 9

$b
[1] 4 5 6
> testObj <- ExampleClass(list('a' = c(1:3), 'b' = c(4:6)))
> newitem <- c(7:9)
> seeLists(testObj)[[2]] <- newitem
> testObj
An object of class "ExampleClass"
Slot "lists":
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right. Is there a place where these kinds of "behaviors" are covered? I currently follow mostly Hadley Wickham's guides.

Comment: I'm not sure, it doesn't seem to be in the help files anywhere. I worked it out by trial and error, though one useful principle to bear in mind is that in R there isn't such a thing as a "`foo[[<-`"-type function so it has to be called in stages.